# Ratio between relative totient function and totient function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Define $\varphi(n,x)$ as the number of elements in the interval $[1,x]$ that is relatively prime to $n$.

Is it true that there exists some constant $c_1,c_2>0$, such that if $x\geq c_1\log n$, then $\frac{\varphi(n,x)}{\varphi(n)} \geq \frac{c_2x}{n}$?

If $c_1$ is too small, we can take $n$ as the product of first $k$ primes, and let $x$ to be the $k$th prime number, and show this is not true.

But if $c_1$ becomes larger, then the above example is no longer a problem.

Comment: For any natural number $m$, observe that if $mn\le x\le(m+1)n$, then $$m=\frac{\varphi(n,mn)}{\varphi(n)}\le \frac{\varphi(n,x)}{\varphi(n)}\le \frac{\varphi(n,(m+1)n)}{\varphi(n)}=m+1\,.$$ It follows immediately that for all $x\ge1$, you can choose $c_2=1$ (and arbitrary $c_1>0$).

Comment: The proof works when $x$ is large, but does not work for small $x$. For example, the argument would show when $x=1$, we obtain $\frac{1}{n} = \phi(n,1)/\phi(n) \leq 2$.